# union instead of aligned_storage_t as part of node type of container

Tags: c++, stl, containers, unions, c++17

Containers `std::list< T >/std::map< T >/std::set< T >` (not full list) to store an elements uses *node types*, which differs from `T`, as opposite to, say, `std::vector` or `std::array`.

If I pass some allocator `A` to them, then it will be "converted" to `node_allocator_type` by means of something like:

```
using allocator_traits = typename std::allocator_traits< A >::template rebind_traits< node_type >;
using node_allocator_type = typename allocator_traits::allocator_type;
```

Standard library implementations ([libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__tree), [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_tree.h#L230)) may use an analogue of [`std::aligned_storage_t< sizeof(T), alignof(T) >`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) as a constituent of the *node type* as a place to store value of type `T`. "Past the end" or "root" elements may have no storage for a value of type `T`. Life circle of the value is "manually" managed by containers by means of using in-place `::operator new` and manual calling of a destructor finally.

Is it valid to use single-element `union` in form

```
union U
{
    U() { ; }
    T value;
};
```

instead of `std::aligned_storage_t< sizeof(T), alignof(T) >`?

Which properties of `std::aligned_storage_t` (internally it may be implemented as a properly aligned array of type `char [sizeof(T)];`) are crucial in the mentioned use case and prevail over all potential advantages of the above `union`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the closer analogue is actually:

```
union U
{
    U() { }
    ~U() { }
    T value;
};
```

in case `T` isn't trivially destructible.

That said, the `union` is going to be necessary when you want a literal type. Can't use placement-new in a `constexpr` constructor so that's out to start with. That's a big win in that direction.

One advantage of `aligned_storage_t` is that you don't need to worry the potential of `T` overloading `operator&()`. `new (&u.value) T` might do something weird and might not compile at all. `new (&storage) T` doesn't have that problem, while being more ergonomic than `new (std::addressof(u.value)) T`.